# About love, fear and hate

Tags: suffixes

If to love or like something is *phile, and to fear something is *phobia, then what is to hate something?

Comment: The word is "phobia".   Not only to to form nouns meaning fear, but also nouns meaning hate, dislike, contempt, or repression of a specific thing.  e.g. homophobia (hate, not fear)

Comment: See prefix miso in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/119823?rskey=iYd2Bv&result=2#eid)

Comment: Hatred isn't necessarily loathing. To my mind, loathing involves an element of repulsion, whereas hatred is entirely self-driven.

Answer (score 1):

You could try *miso-*.

Common example would be: philogyny is love for women

misogyny is hatred for women